# Screenshot Travis Laravel Test

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, travis-ci, google-chrome-headless

I am currently using TravisCI to test my Laravel app. Is there a way to screenshot the headless testing in TravisCI so that I can see the output of the window?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel Dusk, you can use:

```
$this->browse(function(Browser $browser) {
   $browser->visit('http://example.com')
           ->screenshot('sample-screenshot');
});
```

to take screenshot. It's working in headless Chrome so it should work also without any problem in TravisCI